# "Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'HelloHell' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: angularjs

Please give me wher im doing Worng

```
<div ng-app="customCharts">

    <div ng-controller="HelloHell">

    </div>
</div>
```

**Angular**

```
var app = angular.module('customCharts', []);


var app = angular.module('customCharts', ['dx']);

app.controller("ChartController", function ($scope, $http, $q) {
    $scope.productSettings = {
        dataSource: new DevExpress.data.DataSource({
            load: function () {
                var def = $.Deferred();
                $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: 'http://localhost:53640/Home/PostChart'
                }).success(function (data) {
                    def.resolve(data);
                });
                return def.promise();
            }
        }),
        series: {
            title: 'Displays Product Costs for items in our Database',
            argumentType: String,
            argumentField: "Name",
            valueField: "Cost",
            type: "bar",
            color: '#008B8B'
        },
        commonAxisSettings: {
            visible: true,
            color: 'black',
            width: 2
        },
        argumentAxis: {
            title: 'Items in Product Store Database'
        },
        valueAxis: {
            title: 'Dollor Amount'
        }
    }
})
```

**Json Controller**
    public JsonResult PostChart()
            {
                var prod = new List();
                using (Ctxdb db = new Ctxdb())
                {
                    var product = db.Products.ToList();
                    foreach (var p in product)
                    {
                        var thing = new { Name = p.ProductName, Cost = p.Price };
                        prod.Add(thing);
                    }
                }
                return Json(prod, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }

Comment: Duplicate of [THIS SO POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29282647/angularjs-http-get-jsonresult)?  Nevertheless, I don't see issues, other than how you might have loaded the libraries.  Works for me [in this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/m97s6EAhMTRVlU9TQmsm?p=preview).  References [https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/16_1/Guide/Data_Visualization/Basics/Installation/#CDN_Services](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/16_1/Guide/Data_Visualization/Basics/Installation/#CDN_Services)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller in HTML should be

```
<div ng-controller="ChartController">
```

also you should have one module

```
var app = angular.module('customCharts', []);
```

Comment: give me i can check

Comment: 145 715 415     password 4w93wt

Comment: could u plz come back again on that time i lose powersupply

Comment: give the id again

Comment: r  u online available